# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to learn Spring Security, The first example of code is giving error like this when i run a URL "http://localhost:8080/spring-security-helloworld-xml/welcome" and i am using jetty plugin as a server.

**Error:** org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring-security-helloworld-xml/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

This is **web.xml** :

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is my controller **HelloConroller.java** :

```
package com.mkyong.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView welcomePage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
    model.addObject("message", "This is welcome page!");
    model.setViewName("hello");
    return model;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adminPage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
    model.addObject("message", "This is protected page!");
    model.setViewName("admin");

    return model;

}
```

}

This is **mvc-dispacther-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.*" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is **spring-security.xml** :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: what is spring-security-helloworld-xml? Is it your application context or application context is / . How are you hosting this application? I think it's a problem of application context try http://localhost:8080/welcome"

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your `web.xml`

Basically with these lines

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

you're loading `spring-security.xml` as the root context of your app (which is loaded by the `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` defined at the beginning of the `web.xml` since you didn't specify a custom context for it): but this context doesn't seem to have any notion of any bean defined in the `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` (where you actually load the bean `HelloController` via the `component-scan` tag).

Now, I don't know how it is actually structured your project, but to solve it quickly, you might simply include the `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` in the `spring-security.xml`

```
<import resource="[path to web-dispatcher-servlet]" />
```

It s not a really clean solution, but it should work in your case. I suggest you to study a bit Spring IoC container before diving into security. It is true that Spring security works as a filter, though when it comes to configure it, it is quite useful to have an understanding of Spring IoC.

As a mere personal advice, generally a Spring webapp context is structured as follows

- a root context (defining DB connections, transaction management, DAOs and all other general purpose beans)
- a web context, defining mappings and controllers
- a security context, included generally in the root context to take advantage of method security if needed, to define all security related stuff